# Apache poi generated .xls file needs borders

Tags: java, excel, formatting, apache-poi, drools

I need to use an excel .xls file generated by Java code (apache poi) to feed to a drools rules engine. 
drools is not able to read the rows/columns unless i open the spreadsheet, select all the data and set the "All Borders". I tried using the cellStyle option but it doesn't work. The only way i can make it to work is by manually selecting the entire data and set the "All Borders". I am using the older version HSSFSheet as it is a .xls file. Please advice.

Thanks
Aadil

Comment: Can you provide a sample .xls that's causing the problem? Also, which Drools version are you using?

Comment: @laune  Thank you for your response. I am able to fix this issue.  Under the conditions row where i declare the Class and Object i just set the border style to that one row.  We are using drools version 6.2